# Suddenty I cant boot into Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows

Even if I click on Windows, it goes to linux. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Using dual boot. Maybe repair GRUB? I don't have a clue what to try.

Answer (score 1):

boot into Linux

open up a terminal and run this command to update the boot loader.

```
sudo update-grub
```

This command will scan for installed operating systems and add them to the boot menu or update them. I think its just what you need to do.

Comment: didn't work. : (

Answer (score 1):

You could try booting from GRUB command line. For this you need to have some basic information. Take note of the number of the partition where Windows is installed.

Now reboot. When you see the GRUB menu, press the C key in your keyboard. You will be redirected to a GRUB> prompt. Run the following commands, one by one:

set root=(hd0,msdosY)

where Y is the number of the Windows partition;

chainloader +1

if any error occurs in this command, your Windows installation is very probably broken;

boot

if you got to this point, Windows should boot and we're good to go. There is a way to do this without the command line, but first you need to see if this method works.

NOTE: I did not consider the fact that you might have more than one HDD/SD. Say, if your Windows installation is at a second hard drive, in the first partition, run 'set root=(hd1,msdos1)' instead. HDD 3 is (hd2), and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try boot-repair?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Run boot-repair, choose Recommended Repair. And follow the instruction. It will repair your grub, and can also repair your Windows boot file.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work.. looks like Windows is the problem. Now it shows "Windows" but it doesn't boot into Windows. It shows an HP screen and then ultimately goes to linux

Comment: @alejoss then don't try 'recommended options'. Have you try the advanced options? Check the purge and reinstall grub. And repair windows boot files. You might be want to take a look at the other options. I suggest to use live usb to use boot-repair. If you want to give a try. And, make sure you're connected to the internet.